# Подключение AdMob к приложению Android

Tags: android, admob

Всем привет. Хочу выложить приложение в PlayMarket без добавления рекламных блоков AdMod, но в будущем планирую встроить их. Как безболезненно потом совершить процесс встраивания рекламы? Нужно будет собирать новую сборку и реклама появиться только у новых скачавших или обновившихся, или возможно заранее как то предусмотреть?

Comment: А в самом коде встроить проверку типа ответа сервера (да/нет) и показ не получается встроить?

Comment: В том то и дело, с рекламой не работал еще,может и есть такое в AdMob,что можно view подготовить под него,но в коде прятать или не задействовать,пока положительный ответ от проверочного api не придет по запросу

Comment: Будущее с рекламой вообще наступит? :) Есть смысл что-то делать, если это будущее уже определено и запланировано. Иначе, выпускайте как есть.